# How to format model ID in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, primary-key

In Rails, How can I format output of model ID(auto increment primary key) from "12" to something like this "INV000012"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format your id, use [`format`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) !

```
def long_id
  format("INV%06d", id)
end
```

Comment: Is there a benefit (besides readability) over `"INV%06d" % id` (skipping the call to `format`?

Comment: It mostly is readability. See http://batsov.com/articles/2013/06/27/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-2-favor-sprintf-format-over-string-number-percent/ for more info.

Comment: Hi @EricDuminil, Thank you for help. format method works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance method in your model:

```
def custom_id
  "INV" + id.to_s.rjust(6, '0')
end
```